# Is it possible to decorate an event handler to perform a login check?

Tags: c#, .net, python-decorators

I have several event handlers which perform different actions (for example making HTTP requests). I would like to check if the user is logged in before executing code from the event handler.

Currently I do this:

```
private void Publish_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var temp = GlobalVariables.sessionData["loggedUser"];
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

                if (ex is NullReferenceException || ex is KeyNotFoundException) 
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please log in");
                    return;
                }

                throw;
            } 

            publishBTaskPane = new BTaskPane();
            myTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(publishBTaskPane, "Publish");
            myTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(myTaskPane_VisibleChanged);
            myTaskPane.Visible = true;

        }
```

I would like to keep the 'try' clause outside of the event handler.

In Python you can use a decorator.

```
def login_required(handler):
    """
    Decorator which performs a user authentication before a particular handler is executed.
    """
    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user:
            return self.redirect('/login')
        else:
            return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return check_login

class LogoutHandler(BaseHandler):
    """
    Terminate the user session and return them to the login screen.
    """
    @login_required
    def get(self):
        self.auth.unset_session()
        if not self.request.user_agent:
            return self.response.write('OK')
        self.redirect('/login')
```

Is it possible to do something similar in C#, so I don't have to repeat the try clause in each event handler?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be a kind of generic answer, since I don't have a full context of the question to base the answer on, but hopefully you can tweak it to your needs.

First off, the way to get the closest would be to create your own annotation and have it wrap the methods, but that takes a bunch of extra learning (assuming you don't already know it) in order to accomplish.

---

The *simplest* way would to make a function that you call as the first thing in those handlers:

```
public boolean notLoggedIn() {
   try {
      var temp = GlobalVariables.sessionData["loggedUser"];
      return false;
   }
   catch (Exception ex) {
      if (ex is NullReferenceException || ex is KeyNotFoundException) {
          MessageBox.Show("Please log in");
          return true;
      }

      throw;
   }
}
```

Used by the handler:

```
private void Publish_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) {
   if(notLoggedIn())
      return;

   publishBTaskPane = new BTaskPane();
   myTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(publishBTaskPane, "Publish");
   myTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(myTaskPane_VisibleChanged);
   myTaskPane.Visible = true;
}
```

---

Another thing to try is sort of the Execute Around Method pattern. You get your generic logged-in checker to run a lambda of what the method *actually* does. So, using this:

```
public void ifLoggedIn(Action action) {
   try {
      var temp = GlobalVariables.sessionData["loggedUser"];
      action();
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
      if (ex is NullReferenceException || ex is KeyNotFoundException) {
          MessageBox.Show("Please log in");
          return true;
      }

      throw;
   }
}
```

Which can be used by handlers like this:

```
public void Public_Click(object send, RibbonControlEventArgs e) {
   ifLoggedIn( () => {
      publishBTaskPane = new BTaskPane();
      myTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(publishBTaskPane, "Publish");
      myTaskPane.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(myTaskPane_VisibleChanged);
      myTaskPane.Visible = true;
   }
}
```

---

There are a few other ways that "wrappers" can be applied easily that I can think of, but I don't think any will work well with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of the Python decorator in C# is the [member attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx). One difference is attributes are not executed, just accessed via reflection. I wonder if, since C# supports having multiple handlers for one event, you could have one handler for all events that checks to see if the other handler has this attribute, and execute the login check if so.